# How to calculate triangle coordinates in cartesian plane?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, triangles

My problem can be describe by following image:

[image]

I know coordinates of an example `P` point. Say, they are equal to `(8,8)`. I also know the length of `a`, `b` and `c` sides of the triangle which are equal to `10`. Now, how one can calculate the coordinates of `ABC` points?

**SOLVED (11/3/2016)**

Thanks to @EmilioNovati answer to my other question (["How to calculate $B(x_1,y_1)$ when $\alpha$ and $A(x_0,y_0)$ are known?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693348/how-to-calculate-bx-1-y-1-when-alpha-and-ax-0-y-0-are-known/1693353#1693353)), I found a solution to my problem with coordinates of triangle vertices.

First lets look at following drawing:

[image]

Now, in order to calculate $A(x_A,y_A)$, $B(x_B,y_B)$ and $C(x_C,y_C)$, one can do:

$x_C = x_P + a*cos(\alpha)$,
$y_C = y_P + a*sin(\alpha)$;

$x_A = x_P + a*cos(\alpha+\beta)$,
$y_A = y_P + a*sin(\alpha+\beta)$;

$x_B = x_P + a*cos(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)$,
$y_B = y_P + a*sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)$.

Comment: Is $AB$ parallel to the $x$ axis? Also, is $P$ the centroid?

Comment: Yes, $AB$ is parallel to the $x$ axis, and also $P$ is the centroid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

using elemental geometrical properties of equilateral triangles you can see that:

$$
PC=PA=PB=\frac{10\sqrt{3}}{3}
$$

and the distance of $P$ from the sides is half this value.

Can you do from this adding or subtracting such values from the coordinates of $P$ to find the vertices?

Comment: elemental?! wow :)

Comment: Dont'you know that if $l$ is the side of an equilateral triangle the height $h$ is $h=l\sqrt{3}/2$? and the the three heights intersect at a point $P$ such that the distance form a vertex is double the distance from a side? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle#Principal_properties

Comment: Yes, I know. I am just more familiar with the use of "elementary" as opposed to "elemental" in this context. But I looked up the definition and yours is perfectly fine.

Comment: Sorry! My english is so poor :(

Comment: @EmilioNovati I believe that I should use trigonometry here, but I don't know how can I use angles values in calculation of ABC coordinates.

Comment: You don't need trigonometry. Simply look at the figure. You have, $x_C=X_P=8$ and $y_C=y_P+\frac{10\sqrt{3}}{3}$. And you can do analogously for the other points.

Comment: Yeah, but in order to calculate coordinates of $B$ and $A$ I have to use angles?